# Max Value from a field as a condition

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to use the max value of a field as a condition to delete several rows. In my case it's numdoc.

I want to check the max value of it, but i'm fairly new to SQL and i'm not being able to. Currently using c# and MySQL, the code I have right now is this:

```
queryString = "DELETE FROM wgcdoccab WHERE numdoc = MAX(numdoc) serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS' and contribuinte ='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())),120) ";
```

This might be a newbie question and i'm sorry if it is the case, i just would like a good answer, or whether there is a better way to do what i am trying to achieve.

EDIT: The conditions for deleting are: The value serie must equal 1, tipo doc must equal FSS and the date, must be of the previous day, the schema, is basically deleting all the rows line by line, that fall into the condition thats why i want to use the MAX so i can check all the fields one by one with a do\while cycle

Sorry if i dont explain very well, english is not my mother language.

Comment: Need to see additional details about your schema and what your true conditions are for deleting.

Comment: Why are you creating new accounts all the time?

Comment: Hm? im not creating accounts? why do you think that.

Comment: Why do you need to delete the rows line by line?

Comment: i want only to delete the last ones who fit into the condition, its an exercise i was asked to do

Comment: That makes more sense than your last explanation ;)  Probablemente me tartamudear en Español tambien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your condition is to delete rows that have the maximum value of numdoc filtered by the other conditions,

```
DELETE 
FROM wgcdoccab 
WHERE numdoc = (
    SELECT MAX(numdoc) FROM WGCDOCCAB WHERE
    serie ='1' and tipodoc ='FSS' and contribuinte ='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())), 120))
```

Comment: So to use the max numdoc value i first need to select it and then add the conditios, i see thank you!